# How to get a rich text area content without HTML markups

Tags: soql, workbench

While doing an SOQL query, I am getting html tags for Rich Text fields. Is there possibility to get only the rich text area content without the HTML markups in the query itself?

Comment: Nope. Not possible.

Comment: This issue has been resolved in lightning experience but unfortunately for classic users, there's no possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are no SOQL functions that allow you to strip out content (tags or otherwise) from a Rich Text field.

Comment: About the best OP will be able to do is use `String.replaceAll('<[^>]+>',' ')` outside of the query. Snippet shamelessly copied from [a question on developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008ytKIAQ)

Comment: @Derek Except that it's tagged `workbench`, which can't perform post-processing.